# Linux daemon: alternative to chdir("/")?

Tags: linux, daemon, chdir

I have a program (Crafty chess) that works just fine when started from the console. For my application I have daemonized it. When daemonizing a process, one is supposed to change the working directory to "/" via `chdir("/")`.

When I follow that advice, the program exits in some use cases because it doesn't have the proper permissions in "/". When I don't `chdir`, the program works, but just leaving out `chdir` is a crutch.

Is there a sound alternative to omitting `chdir("/")`?

Comment: Can you quote a source for advice of executing chdir("/") I doubt that this is a good idea (for a multitude of reasons) and would be interested to find out where this was advised and why?

Comment: What do you mean by "it doesn't have the proper permissions"? What happens? What doesn't work?

Comment: @RobKielty See http://www.itp.uzh.ch/~dpotter/howto/daemonize. "This prevents the current directory from being locked; hence not being able to remove it."

Comment: If it's exiting for not having permission, why is it writing to the disk anyway? chdir("/") shouldn't be a problem if you're being specific about where to write your files. Also, just because it's recomended to do chdir("/") doesn't mean it's suitable in all instances.

Comment: @Troy: It needs write permission in the working directory. Would it be OK to chdir to some other directory where it has those permissions (e.g. /tmp)?

Comment: @JohnKugelman I have done some more digging around and have found other references to this practise I have to say I would be reluctant to chdir to / and would seek to avoid doing this. I think that root file permissions are protecting the root file system in this instance.

Comment: If you look at `sudo lsof / | grep cwd`, you see how many processes have `/` as their cwd, so it cannot be such a bad idea.

Comment: The idea is that root is always there. As @JohnKugelman points out it is done to prevent locking a directory but there is a caveat, again in JKs answer, the program should only write to files with non relative file paths and preferably not the root filesystem. User level applications, even daemons, as a rule should not write to the root file system for fear of filling it up.

Comment: If a program wasn't specifically written with support to run as a daemon, don't expect it to work without modifying it. Daemons have to take care of some details. See: http://www.netzmafia.de/skripten/unix/linux-daemon-howto.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It probably should not write to the current directory. It'd be better to write to some specific directory instead. Instead of cd'ing to `/tmp` and writing files to the current directory, write files to `/tmp/whatever` — i.e. always use absolute paths.

And on a related note, don't hardcode `/tmp` if you can avoid it. Make it a configuration option, or use the `$TMPDIR` environment variable, or best of all, use `mktemp()`.

Answer (score 0):

You can call the [daemon(3)](http://linux.die.net/man/3/daemon) function (with a non-zero first `nochdir` argument) so that it daemonize a process without doing the `chdir("/")`)

But as John Kugelman suggests, you should not write (nor read) any relative path in a daemonized program (or you should do an explicit `chdir` to a directory that you can read and write and search).